# How reuse Custom Validator in other tests

Tags: c#, .net, testing, nunit

I had a class and I wrote validation rules for it, but then I understand that the exact same validation would be for all classes with `ID`. Then I decided to write an extension to use it everywhere. But I ran into the problem of writing tests. I don't understand how to reuse the test for other classes

i have next validator and model:

```
public class AddValidator : AbstractValidator<AddCommand>
{      
    public AddValidator()
    {
        this.RuleFor(i => i.Id)
            .Cascade(CascadeMode.Stop)
            .CustomIdValidator();
    }
}
public class AddCommand
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

extension witch i want reuse in other validators:

```
public static class IdValidatorExtension
{
        public static IRuleBuilder<T, string> CustomIdValidator<T>(
            this IRuleBuilder<T, string> ruleBuilder)
        {
            return ruleBuilder.NotEmpty().NotNull();
        }
}
```

before i write this extensions i create tests(nUnit)

```
[TestCase("")]
[TestCase(null)]
public void WhenIdNullOrEmptyValue_ShouldThrowError(string id)
{
     this.target.TestValidate(new SomeCommand { Id = id })
         .ShouldHaveValidationErrorFor(i => i.Id);
}
```

model:

```
public class SomeCommand 
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

and now i don't know how to reuse this test in all my model where i have property id

Comment: I am still failing at understanding the problem. You have a validator for `SomeCommand` just like you have for `AddCommand`, don't you?

Comment: i edited the question. In short, there is an extension and there is a test for it ... in models I  use it as: `this.RuleFor(i => i.Id).Cascade(CascadeMode.Stop).CustomIdValidator();` and now not clear how to write a test for new class... there is no need to duplicate code of validator tests

Comment: You could create a Test-BaseClass for Validators including the ID Validation. That's what we did for specific types that share Validator-Settings. The base class then covers things like ID, Name, blah properties which all of the Model-Validators to test share. The thing to keep in mind: The test if the extension validates correctly is a different one. In that base class we basically test only "the appropriate validators have been added". I hope this makes sense?

Comment: @Fildor could show some example?